# Merging customized code in Visual Studio with new version of framework

Tags: visual-studio, merge

*(I use nopCommerce as an example here, but I'm more asking about how the general idea would be accomplished than my specific case.)*

I have a project that uses [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com), and it's a pretty old version. I'd like to update to the newest version, but the official docs say to "remove all old files" and replace them with the new versions. The problem is that we have *heavily* customized the installation, so following that suggestion would be problematic. Is there a way in Visual Studio (2015 or 2013) to go through file by file and **manually** merge an unrelated folder (the new source files) with the existing project?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you start with the old version and commit it to a new git repository (or other source control of your choice). Fork that into two branches, committing your customized code to branch A and the new version to branch B. Merge branch A to branch B. Fix any conflicts and then review the merge diff for anything that didn't conflict but still is not correct. Test the result thoroughly.